# Importing a module with Python from a different folder that imports a module from that same folder

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following situation.
In folder "scripts" I have two python scripts, "master" and "dependent". Master begins with importing several functions and classes from dependent to do something. For example:

```
from dependent import blahblah


#does a function or a class
```

I also have a script one level up (in the folder where "scripts" folder is) that imports stuff from master. It starts like this

```
from scripts.master import whatever
```

But the problem occurs because master imports dependent, and I get error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependent'
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: maybe you should use relative imports - with dot - like `from .dependent import blahblah`

Comment: the trouble is that this is just one example, in reality I have quite a few files in "scripts" that import from each other. but I'll try to add . to each import and see if it fixes it, so tnx for the suggestion

EDIT: yeah, that fixed everything, tnx